# Respect space in code but ignore &nbsp; with CSS?

Tags: css

With CSS can I make a browser ignore the `&nbsp;` character but respect normal white space?

So this:

```
Some text &nbsp;&nbsp;More text
```

Is displayed like this:

Some text More text

Not:

Some text   More text

UPDATE There is actually more white space in my code. I need the default behavior where extra white space doesn't get rendered on the page so I dont think I can use white-space: pre or pre-wrap

So this shouldn't be excessively indent before the initial word.

```
           Some text &nbsp;&nbsp;More text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a pure CSS way of doing that, since `&nbsp;` is an actual character that is different from the whitespace created by the spacebar in a text editor (what gets ignored by HTML renderers). However, depending on how those are appearing, you may be able to use a script that searches for and removes that character wherever it sees it.

Comment: @JordonBedwell - `white-space: pre` doesn't do what the OP wants. He wants to be able to ignore `%nbsp;` characters the same way HTML interpreters ignore standard spaces. Additionally, `pre`, specifically *really* doesn't do it, considering it *preserves all* whitespace.

Comment: @Jordon: It does exactly what I wanted though when google led me to this answer...thanks!

Comment: It made space characters indent the text. I was doing a code-block and wanted it formatted like a <pre> tag, where space characters are used to indent, but using an actual pre tag did something undesireable to the layout. This CSS made it work. Note: my goal was different from the OP, search results for a related but different problem led me here.