# Is it possible to target <p>&nbsp;</p> with just CSS?

Tags: html, css

I know I can remove p tags only with `&nbsp;` being in them with JS/jQuery like so:

```
$("p").filter(function(){
    return $.trim(this.innerHTML) === "&nbsp;"
}).remove();
```

But is it possible to target these with just CSS. Something like these doesn't work:

```
p[&nbsp;] { display: none; }
p:contains('&nbsp;') { display: none; }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Respect space in code but ignore &nbsp; with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749648/respect-space-in-code-but-ignore-nbsp-with-css)

Comment: Welcome to SO, unfortunately I don't think there's a pure css way of accomplishing this.

Comment: would it help if you use `p:empty` ?

Comment: with a `&nbsp;` the `p` is not empty @Asped

Comment: Good post, thanl You for js code example!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible with just CSS. `:contains` used to be part of the CSS3 spec but has now been removed.

Comment: And even if it hadn't been removed it would still not be possible because `:contains()` doesn't mean "contains this exact string *only*"